# How to change system time to default in Linux

Tags: linux, windows

currently I am using w32tm /resync in windows to reset the time to default timezone but how would i be able to do it in Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by 'default timezone'? Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say that LA is 5:00PM right now, but if i change the time to 8:00PM manually, I want to be able to default my time to correct LA time

Comment: You mean, you want to set the clock to the actual current time?  (That's not what the word "default" means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx), I suspect the closest solutions are `ntpd` or `sntp`. For example, you might use [the internet cluster of ntp servers](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/).